# What is the lifetime of an attachment sent to a Discord bot with a slash command, and where is this documented?

Tags: discord

I have a slash command for my bot that allows users to attach an image. My bot stores the attachment URL for later use. How long does this URL remain valid? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

From the official Discord Developer server: https://discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/1079307503403290685

"...attachments last for 2 weeks but that might change in the future so it is intentionally undocumented..."